# Reset Windows 7 group policy settings

Tags: windows, administrator, administration, mmc

For my system, there are two accounts.  I applied a few changes to a secondary account via the group policy object snap-in of Window's management console.  Despite applying these changes to the secondary account, these changes were somehow skipped without myself noticing this and I'm now unable to apply them again -- and some of them have been applied to me, strangely.

Secondly, I'm wondering if there's a resource where I can learn more about Windows administration because frankly, from the way I see these tools at present -- they suck, and have the most awful of interfaces.  Obviously it's my lack of understanding, so perhaps some resource can offer clarity whereby I can address these "loopholes".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you used the local group policy editor.  Group policies are system wide settings and not typically per user.  And it can be a bit complext to get the policy scope correct when you're starting out.  You can run RSOP.msc at the command prompt to get a sense of the settings being applied currently.

The book Group Policy: Fundamentals, Security, and Troubleshooting by Jeremy Moskowitz is a very good beginner Group Policy book.  Jeremy also is a Microsoft MVP who runs a Group Policy focused website and does trainings.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I reset group policy settings? I can't even enable the administrator account.

Comment: If RSOP shows a configured policy item you'll need to reopen the group policy management console and set the policy item back to its default (usually 'Not Configured')